# How can I choose dynamically between append and prepend function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, methods, dynamic

I'm using jQuery to call some data from the controller and insert it in a calendar which is a `table` with days in column. So I have a prev week / next week and a prev day / next system. The four cases are very similar so I want to create one function to manipulate DOM when I receive data.

I've it but my only problems is for choosing dynamically between `prepend()` and `append()` methods.

If I want the prev day / week I need to prepend elements to have it on the left.
If I want to the next week / day I need to append elements to have it on the right.

I found two solutions:

- use a simple condition for each data

```
if(condition){
  // append
}else{
  // prepend
}
```

- create a function dedicated to it

```
  function insertDOM(data, condition = false){
    if(condition){
      // append
    }else{
      // prepend
   }
}
```

But I think it would be better if I can choose dynamically which method to use. Here is an example what I would like:

```
    if(condition){
      methodToUse = append();
    }else{
      methodToUse = prepend();
   }
   // foreach datas:
   parentElement.methodToUse(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function insertDOM(parent, data, condition = 'append') {
    (condition == 'append') ? $(parent).append(data) : $(parent).prepend(data);
}
```